# Ionic Call function inside another function (JS service)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Hey guys so I have the following question : I'm busy with an Ionic mobile app for a project and I need to call a function in another function in one of my services .js Files (pushNotificationService.js)

here is the code :

```
            checkForNewMessage: function () {
            console.log("This is the regID : " + regID);
            console.log($rootScope.regID);

            var data =
            {
                "action": "push_messages",
                "key": systemKey,
                "data":
                {
                    "action": "checkNewMessages",
                    "device_id": regID,
                    "key": systemKey
                }

            };

            console.log(json_encode(data));
            return $http.post(webserviceURL, json_encode(data))
                .then(function (response) {
                    getMsgNotiLocation(); //this is the function not working
                    return response;
                });
            // getMsgNotiLocation();
        },
```

EDIT : here is the getMsgNotiLocation():

```
            getMsgNotiLocation: function () {
            $rootScope.showCounter = true;
            //console.log("This is what gets returned with the regID : " + json_decode(JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem(regID))));
            var theMessagePage = json_decode(window.localStorage.getItem(regID));
            for (var x in theMessagePage) {
                if (theMessagePage[x].read != "true") {
                    console.log("We have gotten this far atleast : " + JSON.stringify(theMessagePage[x].page))
                    if (theMessagePage[x].page === "messages") {
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log(" Afkondigings Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.afkondigMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "calendar") {
                        $rootScope.kalenderMsgCount = $rootScope.kalenderMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log(" Calendar Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.kalenderMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "sponsor") {
                        $rootScope.sponsorMsgCount = $rootScope.sponsorMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("SPONSOR Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.sponsorMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "#/app/schools/2/Academics") {
                        $rootScope.akademieMsgCount = $rootScope.akademieMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Akademie Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.akademieMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "#/app/schools/3/Sport") {
                        $rootScope.sportMsgCount = $rootScope.sportMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Sport Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.sportMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "#/app/schools/4/Culture") {
                        $rootScope.kultuurMsgCount = $rootScope.kultuurMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Kultuur Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.kultuurMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "contact") {
                        $rootScope.kontakMsgCount = $rootScope.kontakMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Kontak Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.Kontak));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "#/app/schools/5/Information") {
                        $rootScope.inligtingMsgCount = $rootScope.inligtingMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Inligting Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.inligtingMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "news") {
                        $rootScope.downloadsMsgCount = $rootScope.downloadsMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Aflaaibaar Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.downloadsMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "#/app/schools/1/Applications") {
                        $rootScope.aansoekMsgCount = $rootScope.aansoekMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Aansoekvorms Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.aansoekMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page === "wallet") {
                        $rootScope.beursieMsgCount = $rootScope.beursieMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Beursie Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.beursieMsgCount));
                    }
                    else if (theMessagePage[x].page = "affiliates") {
                        $rootScope.besigheidMsgCount = $rootScope.besigheidMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount = $rootScope.afkondigMsgCount + 1;
                        $rootScope.msgcount = $rootScope.msgcount + 1;
                        console.log("Besigheidsforum Message recieved and message count : " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.besigheidMsgCount));
                    } else {
                        console.log("Everything failed please recheck the if statements");
                    }

                } else {
                    //The same as if the condition is met but just a - instead of a + 
                }
            }
        },
```

The other function works 100% (getMsgNotiLocation()) because it gets called elsewhere as well. When I try to execute the app I get the following error : 
ReferenceError: getMsgNotiLocation is not defined

I just can't figure out how to do this please any help will be appreciated thanks in advance !

Also I know all the comments between the code is bad and stuff but before release I clean my code nicely its just to keep track where I've done what

Comment: Can you please share your code of getMsgNotiLocation() ?

Comment: Okay I'll edit the message mesage quickly

Comment: If its in the same service, then you have to call the function using 'this' like this. getMsgNotiLocation()

Comment: @ShrutikaPatil going to try it now and let you know how it goes in a few

Comment: That seemed to do the trick thanks. The answer given bySuresh Kumar Ariya  also has the same "answer" in it as well Thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can trying using arrow function

```
return $http.post(webserviceURL, json_encode(data))
                .then((response)=> {
                    this.getMsgNotiLocation(); //this is the function not working
                    return response;
                });
```